# Achieving a transparent blurred navigation bar for dynamic content

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7.1

Prior to IOS 7.1 we could blur the content based on the ios navigation controller properties but after trying the same code in IOS 7.1 it fails to produce the desired blurred effect.I am working on achieving a semi transparent(black color) blurred navigation bar which should blur my content which in my case is a dynamic content containing images present in table view controller.I also tried FXBlurview by adding it as subview on the navigation bar but was unable to acheive the required effect .Any pointers on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it is based on the blurred transparency of ToolBar, you can also add some color to that toolbar for its bar tint property:
This solution is good of you need iOS7 support

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                                              forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIToolbar* blurredView = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds];
[blurredView setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar insertSubview:blurredView atIndex:0];
```